# How to say "I am not a spam bot" for a captcha

Tags: solicitud-de-término

I'm creating a checkbox captcha; in English the text is

> "I am not a spam bot"

What is the proper way to say this for the Spanish language translation?

I should add I'm not necessarily looking for a word-for-word translation, but rather the proper phrase in Spanish that conveys this specific message.

Comment: The literal translation for 'spam' is 'correo basura'. So 'spam robot' is 'robot de correo basura' but it doesn't sound good in Spanish.

Comment: "spam" isn't really the word you want, even in English. You want to filter out all sorts of bots, not just those that generate spam.

Comment: I'd be tempted to go for "No soy un robot spam" (or "No soy un spam robot"). I would have thought spam is now a universally recognised word?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I have seen in most of sites here in Chile:

"Soy humano!" (means you are human being so you are not a bot)

"No soy un robot" (means that in particular you are not a bot)

Remember that Spanish doesn't have a word literally meaning "Spam" since this is a term originated in USA, anyway most people who use a computer will understand you if you say "spam".

I think is a very difficult one...

Comment: marked as answer, I went with "no soy un robot" they seem to be happy with it, thanks

Comment: "spam" es un anglicismo más que aceptado en estos días, no veo ningún problema en usarlo.

Comment: De acuerdo, pero depende del contexto. En desarrollo de sitios y aplicaciones, utilizaría algo más entretenido que la simple traducción literal "no soy un spam-bot". Sólo para marcar una diferencia, usaría (y lo he visto) "soy humano" o "no soy un robot". Pero absolutamente de acuerdo, spam, email y otros términos computacionales se adoptaron como anglicismos. En ese sentido, los españoles son tradicionalmente mas reacios a adoptarlos, principalmente por la riqueza del idioma, siempre se puede adoptar o traducir los términos.

Answer (score 2):

Literally: "No soy un robot de correo basura".

Most adequate translations would be those answered by @Diego Andrés Díaz Espinoza, particularly the second one "No soy un robot".

Comment: lol thanks for the literal one, I was curious if there was a word for junk mail in spanish :)